# Refine X- Axis so that the distances are better recognizable

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a problem. I have a dataframe `df`. I want to plot a scatterplot with the help of seaborn. But I want to change the x- axis. I would like the x-axis to be finer from 4.0 to 5.0. The distances should be smaller, e.g. 4.1, 4.2 or even finer.
How can I set so that the x-axis is displayed finer, so that I can see the values from 4.0 better?

I looked at [seaborn, pylab - changing xticks from float to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327153/seaborn-pylab-changing-xticks-from-float-to-int?rq=1) , [How to change the X axis range in seaborn in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54822884/how-to-change-the-x-axis-range-in-seaborn-in-python)

```py
d = {'review_scores_accuracy': [1.1, 2.0, 4.5, 5.0, 4.9, 4.8, 4.7], 
     'review_scores_rating': [1.1, 2.0, 4.6, 3.9, 4.2, 4.5, 4.2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="review_scores_rating", y="review_scores_accuracy", ax = ax ) 
# ax.set_xlim(1,5)
# ax.set_xticks(1,2,3,4,4.1,4.2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `matplotlib.ticker`, as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44525175/3763302)

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

d = {'review_scores_accuracy': [1.1, 2.0, 4.5, 5.0, 4.9, 4.8, 4.7], 
 'review_scores_rating': [1.1, 2.0, 4.6, 3.9, 4.2, 4.5, 4.2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="review_scores_rating",y="review_scores_accuracy", ax=ax) 
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.1))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Narrow your data range if you just want to plot between 4 and 5.

Comment: Is there also the option to let it start only in 0.1 steps when 4.0 is but it should still start at 1.0

Comment: You'd have to specify that using something like `ax.set_xticks([1, 2, 3, 4, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 5])` instead of the `ticker.MultipleLocator` line

Comment: thank you very much for your help! :)